# How to change Ubuntu with Wayland's 4 finger swipe gesture to a 3 finger swipe gesture?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, wayland, gestures

I have been looking all day everywhere for a place to change the swipe gesture from a 4 finger to a 3 finger swipe. I am NOT looking for something with `xdotool`/`fusuma` because those simply convert a whole gesture into a keyboard key combination.

What I want is the smoothness of switching between workspaces in Ubuntu under Wayland (that is, it follows exactly my fingers' movement like it already does) but with 3 fingers except 4 fingers..

Where is this setting hidden?

Using Ubuntu 18.10 on Wayland

Answer (score -1):

Please search about wmctrl for moving window.

I will implement workspace switcher to new version of fusuma.